Java Swing rendering inconsistencies and flickering
I'm trying to familiarize myself with making GUIs in java and wrote a program that should move a square on the screen depending on WASD key inputs (Following an online tutorial).
However, when running it, it seems that the square flickers and "lags", sometimes rendering smoothly but most of the time not.
Here is my JPanel class, which is where the main stuff happens :
package me.analyzers.scs.game;

import me.analyzers.scs.utilities.KeyPressHandler;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    final int FPS = 240;
    final int tileSize = 16;
    final int scaling = 3;
    final int realTileSize = tileSize * scaling;
    final int widthX = 16;
    final int widthY = 12;
    final int screenWidth = realTileSize * widthX;
    final int screenHeight = realTileSize * widthY;

    Thread mainLoop;
    KeyPressHandler keyPressHandler = new KeyPressHandler();

    public MainPanel() {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.addKeyListener(keyPressHandler);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void startGameLoop() {
        mainLoop = new Thread(this);
        mainLoop.start();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return mainLoop != null;
    }

    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = 0;
        while(isRunning()) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(currentTime-lastTime > 1000/FPS) {
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                tick();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick() {
        switch (keyPressHandler.getLastKey()) {
            case 'w' -> posY-=1;
            case 's' -> posY+=1;
            case 'a' -> posX-=1;
            case 'd' -> posX+=1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(posX, posY, realTileSize, realTileSize);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}



At first I thought this could be caused by concurrency issues, and so I switched up the "main loop" code a lot; I tried conditionally executing it by checking currentTime() with lastTime, I tried doing Thread.sleep, and also tried using swing's Timer class. They all yield the same result.
An interesting thing to note is that if I call repaint() inside the paintComponent() method (causing a loop, I think), it will work fine; but this calls paintComponent() hundreds of times per game loop.
After searching on the net for similar problems and not being able to fix it, I tried running the same jar archive in a Windows virtual machine. Surprisingly, it renders every smoothly! It also appears that the square moves way slower on the Windows machine than on mine. This confuses me a lot because I thought the JVM was supposed to be consistent across all platforms.
EDIT : I've figured out that constant-inputs (this includes spam-clicking on the window) temporarily halt the weird stuttering. This makes me wonder if it's not caused by some process trying to "save CPU time" on my GUI? Does this exist ?
EDIT 2 : Toolkit.sync() successfully solved this issue. I believe it's because of "graphic event buffering" that my window system does (which explains the constant-input halting the stuttering).

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Concurrency in Swing section.

You need to study that as your 'business' is going on in the wrong thread. Modifications to your gui should be done in the Event Dispatch Thread

It is not permitted to make Swing calls in any thread other than AWT’s dedicated event thread.  Don’t try to make a new Thread;  using javax.swing.Timer instead.  Also, never dispose of a Graphics object unless you created it.  Those things aside, your rendering issues mostly likely will be fixed by a call to Toolkit.sync after each repaint.

g2d.dispose(); -- this is not the cause of your current problem but could cause future problems. Never dispose of a Graphics object given to you by the JVM as this can break the painting chain. Only dispose of Graphics objects that you yourself create. Casting doesn't count as creating.

For what it's worth, I copied the code from your question and added my own implementation of class KeyPressHandler as well as a main method to launch the app and it seems to work fine for me.

@VGR Thank you, Toolkit.sync() solved my stuttering problems ! I believe this was because my window system does buffering of graphic events, which would also explain why spamming inputs "forced" it to update right now, removing the stutter. Please make an answer so I can accept it !

The main reason for this is that you need to call getToolkit().sync() after every repaint.
However, it’s not your only issue.  You must not dispose of a Graphics object unless you yourself created it.  The Graphics passed to paintComponent does not belong to you.  Swing created it, and only Swing may dispose of it.  Interfering with that may cause painting issues.
Another problem is your use of a Thread.  All Swing methods must run in the single, dedicated thread for AWT and Swing operations.  If you call those methods from another thread, they may work sometimes and fail at other times.  Or they may only work on certain computers.  If you want to be sure your program works every time, on every computer, avoid calling Swing methods from a different Thread.  (All of this is documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ .)
The correct way to run Swing code at regular intervals is with javax.swing.Timer.  (This is not the same class as java.util.Timer!)  For example:
Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / FPS,
    e -> {
        tick();
        repaint();
        getToolkit().sync();
    });
timer.start();


Your program should start like this:
class Program {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> { 
         gui = new Gui();
      });
   }
}

class Gui extends JFrame {

   public Gui() {
      .....
      .....
      setVisible( true );
   }

....
....

}

This way, your whole program will run on the event thread.
On the other hand, the setVisible( true );, must be in the last line of the constructor (it can be followed by the listener assignment).
By making these corrections, your problem will probably go away.

“This way, your whole program will run on the event thread.”  No, it won’t.  That is what EventQueue.invokeLater is for.  As in, EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Gui());.

@VGR, Thanks for your comment, I corrected it.
